# Prove that differentiability implies continuous partial derivatives

Tags: real-analysis

In Rudin Thm 9.21, **f** is differentiable, we want to prove $D_jf_i$ is continuous,

we have $(D_jf_i)$x = ($(f')$(x)$e_j)$$\cdot$$u_i$

then $(D_jf_i)(y)-(D_jf_i)(x)$ = {$[f'(y)-f'(x)]e_j$} $\cdot u_i$

$|(D_jf_i)(y)-(D_jf_i)(x)|$ $\leq$ $| [f'(y)-f'(x)]e_j|$ $\leq$ ||$ [f'(y)-f'(x)]$||

For the last step, I don't see why being bounded by $|| [f'(y)-f'(x)]||$ shows it's continuous

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, my bad. The theorem states that if f is **continuously differentiable**, i.e. $||[f′(y)−f′(x)]|| < \epsilon$,  then it's partial derivatives are continuous.